# Ruby Network programming with libnet4r or similar gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, libnet

Please I need particular gem to control my packets and allow me to craft tcp packets (build and injection tcp packets).

actually , **[libnet4r](http://rubydoc.info/gems/libnet4r)** is doing what exactly I need but is seems no longer working with ruby 1.9.x , So is there any update of new name for it or a similar gem doing the same grate job of this lib ?

Comment: Why isn't it working with ruby 1.9? Maybe you can fix it yourself and create a working libnet4r branch for ruby 1.9..

Comment: It seems from the project page that it was last patched or added to in 2007, so it probably can be thought of as deprecated. How about you write a C extension that uses the underlying `libnet`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right ,, it's no longer developed or maintained!.

You Can use [**PacketFu**](http://rubydoc.info/gems/packetfu) instead of lbnet4r it's Great and useful and easy to use.

[Here a great slide](http://www.slideshare.net/keith55/manipulating-the-network-with-packet-fu) about it , too

[Home Page](http://www.packetfu.com/)

HTH , specially for Hackers ;)
thanks guy